# Identity Server 4 Cors Issue

Tags: c#, .net-core, identityserver4, plesk

I've created a token server in .Net Core 2.0 using IdentityServer4.  However I'm running into cors issues on Plesk (for windows), but not locally.  I'm seeing an error message:

> Failed to load https://www.mywebsite.com/.well-known/openid-configuration: Redirect from 'https://www.mywebsite.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' to 'https://mywebsite.com/.well-known/openid-configuration' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://stgapp.mywebsite.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I have Cors configured in my startup like so:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("MyPolicy", builder =>
{
    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowCredentials();
}));
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("MyPolicy");
}
```

From IdentityServer I've AllowAll Origins just to get this test running

```
var loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
var identityServerCors = new DefaultCorsPolicyService(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DefaultCorsPolicyService>())
{
    AllowAll = true
};
```

Yet I'm still receiving cors error.  Does anyone know what else I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally took me a week to fix.  I'm not sure if this is a bug in IDSVR4 or my browser,  but it turns out that Plesk was by default configured with a permanent redirect from http://www.mywebsite.com -> http://mywebsite.com.  So when my popup was loading I always was receiving a cors error.  removing the redirect fixed the issue